# java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset in jdbc error

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I get an error trying to execute this code.

My requirement is to use `getInt()` to convert a string in to DB.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    int t = rs.getInt(i);

    temp = Integer.toString(t);
    if (temp.length() == 1) temp="00"+temp;
    else if (temp.length() == 2) temp="0"+temp;
    else temp=temp;
    output=output+temp;
       ...
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your result set has fewer than seven rows, so you run out of them in the for loop.  It's a good idea to check `rs.hasNext()` to see if there are any more rows to process.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the relevant piece of code (but it's visible in the screenshot), which is the `while` loop preceding the `for` loop you included:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    blah blah blah
}
```

That loop reads all rows from the SQL `select` statement, leaving the `ResultSet` fully consumes (aka exhausted).

When you then `rs.getInt(i)` after `rs.next()` returned `false`, you are told, *"sorry, no can do, you already used all the data"*, aka `SQLException: Exhausted Resultset`.